# Get thread start address

Tags: multithreading, delphi, process, get

I'm writing a process viewer, its 99% complete, I just need get the start address of a process' thread, but I don't know how do it.
Can anyone help-me? :/
Thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`NtQueryInformationThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function passing the [ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS.html#ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress) value of the [THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS.html) enumeration as parameter.

check this sample app

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  TlHelp32,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;


const
  THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION   = $0040;
  STATUS_SUCCESS             = $00000000;
  ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress = 9;

type
  NTSTATUS = LONG;
  THREADINFOCLASS = DWORD;

function NtQueryInformationThread(
    ThreadHandle: THandle;  ThreadInformationClass: THREADINFOCLASS;
    ThreadInformation: Pointer; ThreadInformationLength: ULONG;  ReturnLength: PULONG): NTSTATUS; stdcall; external 'ntdll.dll';

function OpenThread(dwDesiredAccess: DWord;
                    bInheritHandle: Bool;
                    dwThreadId: DWord): DWord; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';


function GetThreadStartAddress(th32ThreadID : DWORD) : Pointer;
var
  hThread : THandle;
  ThreadStartAddress : Pointer;
begin
  Result:=0;
  hThread := OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION , false, th32ThreadID);
  if (hThread = 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    if NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, @ThreadStartAddress, SizeOf(ThreadStartAddress), nil) = STATUS_SUCCESS then
      Result:=ThreadStartAddress
    else
    RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
      CloseHandle(hThread);
  end;
end;

function GetThreadsList(th32ProcessID:DWORD): Boolean;
var
  hSnapshot     : THandle;
  NextThread    : Boolean;
  TThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;
begin
  hSnapshot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0); //Takes a snapshot of the all threads
  Result := (hSnapshot <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  if Result then
    try
      TThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TThreadEntry);
      NextThread := Thread32First(hSnapshot, TThreadEntry);//get the first Thread
      while NextThread do
      begin
        if TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = th32ProcessID then //Check the owner Pid against the PID requested
            Writeln(Format('Thread Id %.8x Start Address %p',[TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID, GetThreadStartAddress(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID)]));
        NextThread := Thread32Next(hSnapshot, TThreadEntry);//get the Next Thread
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    end;
end;

begin
  try
    GetThreadsList(4028);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  readln;
end.
```

Note : to get access to some system process you will need set `SeDebugPrivilege` privilege in your app.

Comment: Hi RRUZ, I got this error: 'A Call to an OS function failded"

Comment: Do you modified the sample code? What version of delphi ar you using?

Comment: Hi RRUz, I'm trying to use only GetThreadStartAddress function, because I already have the GetThreadList funcion.

Comment: but you modified the GetThreadStartAddress function? also what version of delphi are you using?

Comment: I don't modified. I'm using Delphi 7.

Comment: The types NativeUInt and NativeInt are wrong defined in Delphi 7 they have a size of 8 bytes and must be 4, the buffer passed to the `NtQueryInformationThread` must be of 4 bytes (in X86), so you must  replace the `NativeUInt` types in the `GetThreadStartAddress` function by DWORD.

Comment: GetThreadStartAddress should return a pointer rather than an integer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't see any issue (except with old versions of delphi, see my above comment) using NativeInt or NativeUInt for pointer-based values.

Comment: Of course it carries the same information but why do it that way? Why is an integer better than Pointer? What drove that choice?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , I modified a function of a personal library to fit with requiriments of the OP, in that library i use NativeInt as return value just to avoid make additional casts. But i will edit the answer and change to Pointer, becasue in that way the code will be compatible with old versions of delphi too :)

Comment: @paulohr, i modified the function, now is compatible with delphi 7 too.