# How to retrieve start address of a thread using its ID?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to get the start address of a thread using it's ID. Is it possible?

Comment: @Flo What do you mean by pthreads?

Comment: Well you tagged your post with C... I'm asking if your using the POSIX api or if your just using the system call "fork" to spawn threads.

Comment: @flo: `fork` creates a process, not a thread.

Comment: @Flo I'm using windows API functions such as takesnapshot32. dese it matter?

Comment: @ThePianist: It does since the various threading implementations are very different. Escpecially between various operating systems.,

Comment: @ThiefMaster Today a lot of people interchange the word process and thread and thus I was trying to figure out exactly what type of implementation The Pianist was approaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not really trivial for the following reason: in the Win32 subsystem *all* threads have the same start address. In Windows up to (but not including) Vista it was inside `kernel32.dll` (named `BaseThreadStartThunk` according to the official symbols). In Windows versions starting with Vista, the common start address is now `RtlUserThreadStart` in `ntdll.dll` (and `BaseThreadStartThunk` got renamed to `BaseThreadInitThunk` and seemingly only does the Win32-specific tasks now).

However, what you could *attempt* is to suspend the thread, retrieve its `CONTEXT` (using `GetThreadContext`) and from that traverse the stack back to its top to investigate the parameters there. It will require some reverse-engineering of each implementation of the `kernel32.dll` thread start routine, but it should be doable.

An alternative is to use the undocumented native API [`NtQueryInformationThread`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtQueryInformationThread.html) with `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress`. There is also [an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283.aspx) about the function, but it is far from complete.

Comment: Why is NtQueryInformationThread not documented when msdn completely describe it?

Comment: Not to quibble about semantics, you're not supposed to be using the low-level Nt* functions in kernel32.dll: you're supposed to use the higher-level Win32 functions instead.  Per MSDN:  "NtQueryInformationThread may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows. Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this topic."

Comment: @rkosegi: because MSDN *does not* describe it completely. Added a link to a *more* complete, though not necessarily complete documentation. I recommend the book from Nebbett. Side-note: MS only documented it after pressure from the EU etc.

Comment: @paulsm4: the native functions exist in `ntdll.dll` (UM) and `ntoskrnl.exe` (KM), not in `kernel32.dll`. Your point is duly noted, but both from experience (since NT4) and from the simple fact that they're used even by tools MS wrote ("Resource Kit") it's highly unlikely they'll truly change or be unavailable. But the chance is there ...

Comment: MSDN [does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describe `NtQueryInformationThread` much better than what you have linked to, although it might have just been updated recently (do MS people roam SO?!).

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: two things here. Wow - you consider even the linked version any better than what I linked even though MS' docs do not reference the vast majority of information classes suypported? Yes, at least one guy from MS, the author of the oldnewthing blog, Raymond Chen "roams" here :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to [OpenThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and call [NtQueryInformationThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

with second parameter set to `ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress`

Also refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159516/get-thread-start-address)

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I add It's library to my project?

Comment: You have to use LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress() to use this funciton.

Comment: @John: only `GetModuleHandle` not `LoadLibrary`. +1 for the link with the sample code.