# What is the Microsoft-supported API for retrieving a thread's address

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

I am currently using 
`NtQueryInformationThread(.., ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, addr, ..)` for getting the thread address in `addr`. 
The [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> NtQueryInformationThread may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows

Also,

> Note that on versions of Windows prior to Windows Vista, the returned start address is only reliable before the thread starts running.

What is the suggested method for retrieving a thread's address?

Comment: The start address of a thread doesn't seem very useful, especially compared to a thread id or thread handle. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: As any native API `NtQueryInformationThread` carries the warning, but it is highly unlikely that it will come to that. The way I have done this in the past was by walking up the stack of the thread (retrieving the stack pointer from `CONTEXT`) after suspending the thread. Worked for me, but all Win32 processes share the actual start address, which is an internal function in `kernel32.dll` ... not too useful. You're probably looking for the next one in the call stack.

Comment: @GregHewgill Just stumbled upon this piece of code that used this API, so I dont know why start address is needed. For whatever purpose its being used, I just wanted to make this API conform to the msdn standards, that's all.

Comment: @0xC0000022L You are referring to the process start address, not the thread start address. Right?

Comment: @Lelouch Lamperouge: Today's Word of the Day is [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).  And 0xC00000022L is correct: even though it's not useful, it's also not likely to change :)

Comment: @Lelouch Lamperouge: nope, I am referring to the thread's start address. Since the Win32 subsystem requires the thread to be registered in specific ways, when you create a (Win32) thread, the address is always a function in `kernel32.dll`. But since the first thread in a process is also a thread, you're likely right about this, too. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887866

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NtQueryXxxx group of functions are internal Windows kernel functions that were undocumented.  Until Microsoft was forced to document them in the settlement with the USA Department of Justice.  They did so, but reserved the right to alter their implementation in any future version of Windows, necessary to allow them to innovate on Windows.  And reserved the right to not have to make the function actually useful beyond its intended use in the kernel.

The warning is very accurate, you will not get a usable thread start address from this function after the thread was started.  It will point to the *real* start address, an internal helper function named __RtlUserThreadStart() in ntdll.dll.  You can see it back in any stack trace when you've got debugging symbols for Windows.  The same start address for *every* started thread.

The writing is on the wall.  Don't use it.

Comment: THanks for the info. I need some clarity though. 1. What is a **usable** thread start address? I only want to know the real start address. 2. What API should I be using then?

Comment: There is no api that gives you what you want.

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge: what do you mean by "real start address"? The `__RtlUserThreadStart()` one or the one that was passed to the `CreateThread()` API?  Or maybe the one that was passed to `_beginthread()`/`_beginthreadex()` (which if those functions are used will be different than what the runtime passes to `CreateThread()`)? There's probably not a great answer to your question until you can tell people what the thread start address is being used for.

Comment: @Hans: Could you please provide an authoritative resource for the claim that `RtlUserThreadStart` is being used for *all* threads? To my knowledge Win32 threads have a start address named `BaseThreadStartThunk` (or `BaseThreadInitThunk`) according to MS' own symbols. I pointed this out in a comment to the question, too. Referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887866 ...

Comment: BaseThreadInitThunk is the next stack frame, called by RtlUserThreadStart.  I'll defer to my debugger to be the authority.  Just try it.

Comment: @Michael Burr, I was referring to __RtlUserThreadStart() one.

Comment: @Hans: Well, your answer is limited to Vista and up, the question wasn't, though. The general concepts apply still, of course. Windows XP has `BaseThreadStartThunk` but *neither* `RtlUserThreadStart` nor `BaseThreadInitThunk`. Looking at the names, it makes now sense why `BaseThreadStartThunk` became named `BaseThreadInitThunk` in the new Windows versions.