# Details of a thread in Powershell

Tags: powershell, query-optimization, windbg, remote-server, powershell-4.0

How can I get the **CPU consumption** of all threads running in a process thru powershell, in a format similar to this

[image]

I can't find any processor information when I run `gwmi win32_thread|select -First 1`. And the `Start Address` is numeric !?!

Comment: @Neolisk Is this achievable thru Powershell?

Comment: @RRUZ The code in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159516/get-thread-start-address?answertab=active#tab-top`  comes closest to what I am looking for. But how do I run it thru Powershell and for a remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine with PowerShell 7.3.3

```
(Get-Process -ProcessName taskmgr).Threads|Sort-Object TotalProcessorTime -Descending| 
    Format-Table -Property Id,PriorityLevel,ThreadState,WaitReason,StartTime,TotalProcessorTime
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ayan;
Have you looked at PowerDbg on Codeplex?

http://powerdbg.codeplex.com/

Comment: This enables you to control Windbg thhru Powershell. One would need to  get a Procdump to get the thread details for a given process. I am looking to get the thread details live; from a machine's memory. Just like Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

**Showing the same details as Process Explorer**

The screenshot you provided seems to be a screenshot of Process Explorer, not of task manager. This makes things more complex, because (if I recall correctly) Process Explorer uses a kernel driver to get detailed information about the system in order to account CPU time more precisely than Windows does.
I don't have the book at hand, but this should be described in [Windows Sysinternals Administrator's Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073565672X).

**Converting start addresses to DLLs and methods**

The start address, as the name says, is an address. Usually it would be displayed in hexadecimal format, but actually it's just a number, so it may be numeric in your case. Converting to Hex is no problem.

If you want to turn the number into something useful like a DLL name and a method name, you need to use symbols. See in your screenshot: Process Explorer also needs to download symbols, otherwise the offset is calculated from DLL start (as in `van.dll+1c904`).

In order to deal with symbols, Process Explorer uses a Microsoft DLL called `dbghelp.dll`. You have configured that in `Options/Configure symbols...`. You can use the same DLL if you like, but I would say that this is the point where you stop using Powershell, because `dbghelp.dll` is a native DLL and cannot be used by .NET. You can't even create a .NET interop assembly in Visual Studio, because it is not a COM DLL.

In addition, Process Explorer applies another magic to the display value of start address: usually the start address is always the same: some Microsoft code which creates a Thread object which then calls the application specific code. Process Explorer walks up the stack trace and displays the first non-Microsoft frame on the call stack. I'm not sure if the address rturned by WMI considers the same thing.

If you want to give `dbghelp.dll` a try, the method to convert from an address to a DLL should be [IDebugSymbols::GetNameByOffset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also note that the conversion from the address to the method needs to be done on the remote machine, because only the remote machine will know which exact version of the DLL is loaded. Then, also consider that the remote machine needs Internet access in order to download the symbols from the Microsoft server.

**Remote execution**

In the comment you mentioned that you want to execute the command on a remote computer.
Process Explorer does not support remote machines. While I'm not sure about the reasons, my guess is that it would only be able to access the remote PC via WMI - and therefore encounter the same limitations as you did.

However, there are some [alternatives to Process Explorer, discussed in the Process Explorer Forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/process-explorer-to-explore-a-remote-machine_topic15884.html). They also seem to suffer from WMI limitations, but you might give them a try.
Besides that, you can execute programs on remote machines using [SysInternals PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx).

**Overall conclusion**

I guess the expected solution is far too complex to be answered on StackOverflow, especially if the toolset is limited to Powershell. It would at least need C++ for integration of `dbghelp.dll` as well as `PSExec` to access the remote machine.

Comment: `Jagos` seems to have already figured this out.

http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=111&sid=4ab0a360c3bc9957ec102319dc5ef6ad

But I am unable to replicate the solution. Could you try it out.

Comment: None of those Process Explorer alternatives have the ability to display CPU utilization and the `Start Address` of a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can be done with powershell out-the-box, but since you're offering bounty, I'll suggest looking at the source codes from Process Hacker.

http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

IIRC process hacker is written in C, and is fully open sourced.

[Clear the windows 7 standby memory programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841845/clear-the-windows-7-standby-memory-programmatically/20585554#20585554)

Comment: also I was going to mention I've had no success with the Win32_Thread on W7, when testing from powershell or wmi code creator every query results in error / failure.  i.e. no results

Comment: There is a piece of code mentioned here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159516/get-thread-start-address?answertab=active#tab-top

However, I wasn't able to run it. Can you tell if there is a way to run it from Powershell. I'll probably have to compile the code. Although, I am able to run 
`gwmi win32_thread|select -First 1`  

`StartAddress: 1415399312`

But I don't know how to translate the start address to functions.

Comment: I am an admin guy; deployments, backups, clustering and visualization mostly. I couldn't, from the Process Hacker source code, figure out which command or function was responsible for retrieving the `Start Address` of a thread. A piece of code, be it anything, that I could run from the Powershell console would be really helpful.

Comment: not sure if you'll need the SeDebugPrivilege or not for these particular processes.   But here is how you can grant it on the fly with powershell.   http://superuser.com/questions/693620/how-to-restore-the-ownership-of-a-folder-to-trusted-installer-using-silent-com/693627#693627   `Enable-Privilege SeDebugPrivilege`

Comment: Grant what ?  Which processes ?

Comment: Grant SeDebugPrivilege to your running powershell session.  RRUZ mentions it here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159516/get-thread-start-address?answertab=active#tab-top